Nifi pass output of ExecuteProcess to ListFile processor

I have generated a FlowFile using ExecuteProcess (ls command with multiple filters)
I am able to get File names one by one using SplitText
Now output FlowFile contains multiple flowfiles with filename in it.
My requirement is to read this file using GetFile processor
How can i pass this list of files to FetchFile processor so it can read it, FetchFile is unable to read file name from FlowFile

How can i pass this list of files to FetchFile processor so it can read it, FetchFile is unable to read file name from FlowFile
